# Updating height of widgets in React through class name available in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a widget in my React app which does not have a height attribute. However, I can edit the div that shows up in my DOM to fit my needs. I can not access that div thorough my code to adjust the height.
This is my widget:

```
<TradeViewChart
   pair="BTCUSDT"
   interval="1m"
   chartLayout={{
     layout: {
     backgroundColor: "black",
     textColor: "white",
     },
     grid: {
      vertLines: {
       color: "transparent",
      },
      horzLines: {
       color: "transparent",
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

This is how it appears in the DOM:
[image: div in DOM]

I need to access this `class` and adjust the height. How can I do that?

The following screenshot shows the difference between adjusted and unadjusted height"
[image: expected vs reality]

How do I access that class in my code so I can adjust the height for my widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overwrite css that is in a `style` attribute you need to use `!important`
try this:

```css
.tv-lightweight-charts {
  height: 22px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.chat-img .chartContainer .tv-lightweight-charts{
   height: 20px;
}
```

please re-check spellings of classes

Comment: That did not work

Comment: Checked the spelling, not working

Comment: you have to use !important to overwrite inline styling